# в списке текст передвигается при применений псевдокласса :hover

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Я применила псевдокласс :hover, но когда навожу мышку на список, у меня двигается весь список. 
Можете подробно объяснить в чем ошибка, чтобы в будущем не допускать её снова.

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

body {
  width: 100% height: 100vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  width: 1170px
}

.header-bg {
  height: 94px;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 42px;
}

.list-link {
  color: #868686;
}

.list-link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.list-link:active {
  color: white;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ffbb42;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Pricing Table</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">How it work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Happy Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list-link {
  color: #868686;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 13.5px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover .list-link {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffbb42;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Pricing Table</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">How it work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Happy Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="list-link">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```